# Cash Register Key Locations

Tags: escape-from-tarkov

On the map Interchange, I am looking for the cash register keys to unlock them for roubles, however, I haven't had any luck on finding any of them.

What are their spawn locations (picture would be nice) and on what map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The subreddit for Escape From Tarkov has the answer, on [this topic](https://www.reddit.com/r/EscapefromTarkov/comments/8dy8no/interchange_key_guide/):

> I collected a bunch of info for the Shoreline keys so I thought I
> would help out and do the same thing for Interchange as well.
>
> I will try to gather and post all known info as of right now and as it
> develops. Feel free to post a comment if you find a new key spawn not
> yet known to help everyone out! If you can get screenshots of what's
> inside the room too that would be great.
>
> [...]
>
> I will try providing pictures for all of the known keys for easier finding.
> Make sure to bookmark this page as I'll be updating it constantly as more info comes in

As said, the topic will be updated as more info comes in, though I'll describe all cash register keys known for now.

### Key to OLI Cash Register

It is located near the escalators in one of the office. Here are several screenshots to locate it. [Original Imgur post here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8Hzm.jpg).
[image]
[image]
[image: The OLI back offices (through the small door with the light)]

The OLI back offices (through the small door with the light)

[image]

### Key to IDEA Cash Register

It is located on a bus outside the IDEA Store.
[image]
[image]

### Key to Goshan Cash Register

It is located on customs, in a bus behind a gas station.
[image]

### TAR2-2 Cash Register

At the time of writing this answer, no info was available about this cash register on the subreddit topic. Its wikia page only shows [a close screenshot](https://escapefromtarkov.gamepedia.com/Cash_register_TAR2-2).

### Conclusion

This is all known info about cash register keys for Escape From Tarkov. I will keep this answer updated as more info comes in.

Contributors as quoted on the subreddit topic:

> - RusskiEnigma
> - whirlwindtorn
> - _BigMeech
> - GBBUTT